# Зачем мне использовать Webpack/Gulp/Babel с React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, gulp, babel

Помогите пожалуйста собрать мне осколки картины в единое целое. Дело в том, что на данный момент я создаю web-приложения с помощью React'a, так же я использую препроцессор SCSS, с установленной библиотекой для автоматической компиляции node-sass. Всё вроде бы работает, и работает не плохо, но меня постоянно интересовал вопрос зачем же нужны Webpack, Gulp, Babel. Я начал их изучение, но сильно теряюсь в понимании, т.е. написанно, что wepback, что Gulp собирают все файлы в единое целое или же помогают стартовать сервер, делать деплой и тп. Но зачем всё это нужно, если реакт и так собирает сам все файлы в один, а тот же Jenkins делает через git деплой на мой сервер. В тоже время как node-sass сам компилит мой SCSS. Т.е. зачем ставить всё это отдельно, если по-умолчанию всё и так есть. Зачем они нужны на бэке, если тот же node express в состоянии сам подняться, сам собраться. Я дико извиняюсь если мой вопрос кажется вам крайне тупым, но я был бы очень признателен если бы вы помогли мне разобраться в этом, ибо я запутался. Я не прошу объяснить мне работу каждой этой технологии, я лишь прошу объяснить зачем их использовать в связке с такими фреймворками как React, Angular, Vue или же Meteor, Express или т.п. Я смотрю туториалы, читаю статьи и везде всё начинается с того, что мы инициализируем пустой проект, создаём файлики по отдельности и с помощью этих технологий начинаем их объединять и всё такое, но зачем это делать когда можно поставить фреймворк?? Заранее благодарен за ваши ответы.

Comment: реакт и так собирает сам все файлы в один - э, что? Если вы про Create React App, то он таки использует под капотом webpack и babel

Comment: Да, я про Creacte React App, да, я понимаю что оно находится под капотом, я как раз и имел ввиду зачем мне их использовать если они уже есть под капотом? Я не раз видел как ребята ставят webpack  в связку с Create React App, какую же тогда роль webpack должен исполнять в этой связке?